# How to create setup project to run worker service wrote in (.net core project)

Tags: installation, project, worker, service-installer

I wrote worker service in .net core , how can I run it via setup project , to download the .exe worker service on client servers, how to run worker service as windows service on clients server?

I tried to make setup project and addede .exe in published worker service, when I tried to run the setup file , the service doesn't work